# How to get an account with the FIWARE labs

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion, fiware-cygnus, fiware-wirecloud, fiware-cosmos

I want to learn about FIWARE. I found out about FIWARE labs and tried to register in it. I was unable to register with them.

Unfortunately after repeted attempts, I was not able to register with the same. Everytime i would be getting a varification mail and every time as soon as i reply i would be getting the reply that that mail is held up for review. Can anyone help me on how to solve it.

Comment: Have you tried contacting the help desk at: `fiware-lab-help@lists.fiware.org` ?

Comment: I was checking the logs and there is a problem with the length of your email account. I suggest trying a short one to get an account.